# In BrightSpotCMS HOWTO inspect the "request" object from HttpServlet before the JSP is rendered for a "Content" object

Tags: java, jsp, content-management-system, scriptlet

In many MVC frameworks when a request is made it goes to a controller/action class (based on the URL pattern among other things). If the developer wants to do something with the `request` object or other processes then it does that with in the `execute` or `doGet` or `doPost` etc methods & then forwards it to the dispatcher. The response type could be a JSON, JSP, XML etc.

I have a [brightspot cms](http://www.brightspotcms.com/) webapp in which I want to do something similar. It is based on the open source project [dari framework](http://www.dariframework.org/).

In case of a object of type `Content` if I want to setup some pre-processing of variables to be used in the JSP page based on the `request` object, how can I do it? I am unable to find the point of intervention between the request going to conten type object AND `request` being forwarded to the backing JSP page.

I know I can just add scriptlets to the JSP page, but I had rather not do it [for variety of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: There's a discussion site for BrightspotCMS [here](http://community.brightspotcms.com/) that, while it doesn't have a lot of content yet, is worth asking questions on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding a Filter for the URL pattern I was interested in. [More info here.](http://community.brightspotcms.com/discussions/questions/536-howto-inspect-the-request-object-from-httpservlet-before-the-jsp-is-rendered-for-a-content-object)